# when checkbox checked value true, display text not displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hello I can't see text when checked value true. How can open default this area?

Important!
When checkbox checked, text must be visible!!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked="true"> <!-- checked value true -->

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

added code snippet, when click run code snippet can see checked checkbox.

Comment: When I uncheck and check the box the text becomes visible. Isn't that what you want? I'm not clear on the problem. If you want the text to show up when the page loads, either don't hide it by default as you're doing or call the function

Comment: Your text has *style="display:none"*. Remove that and it will be shown from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must delete `style="display:none"` in text,
because you're hiding that directly related element

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked="true"> <!-- checked value true -->

<p id="text" >Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Display some text when the checkbox is checked:

```
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked="true" />
<!-- checked value true -->

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
    var text = document.getElementById("text");
    if (checkBox.checked == true) {
      text.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      text.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  window.onload = () => {
    myFunction();
  };
</script>
```

Wokring example
Just add `window.onload`
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)

Answer (score 1):

if i am correct you are trying to display the text on body load when the check box is already checked.

**- first option: call the function `myFunction()` on body load `<body onload="myFunction();">`**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked="true"> <!-- checked value true -->

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**- second option:  remove the style css `display:none` from `<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>`**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Display some text when the checkbox is checked:</p>

<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()" checked="true"> <!-- checked value true -->

<p id="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `p` element to be displayed just remove the initial `display: none` from here

```
<p id="text">Checkbox is CHECKED!</p>
```